# ¿ Cómo imprimir un área específica con javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

acudo a ustedes ya tengo problemas al imprimir un área especifica con javascript, bueno pasa que yo quiero imprimir un modal en el cual se encuentra un modelo de reporte de ventas, entonces que cuando al hacer click en el boton me abre una nueva ventana en otra página "_blank" con los datos a imprimir...

Tengo dos botones que me funciona llamados "print 1" y "print 2" en caso de print 1 me obtiene los datos correctamente pero luego de imprimir cierro la ventana y no me funcionan los botones el cual debo de recargar nuevamente la página y eso no deseo, y en caso del boton print 2 si me funciona y abre en otra página pero el problemas es que no me obtiene los estilos como el del boton print 1...

¿ Cómo podria solucionar estos problemas ?
aquí mi código..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable();
  $("#imprimir").on('click', function() {
    var contenido = document.getElementById("impri").innerHTML;
    var contenidoOriginal = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = contenido;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = contenidoOriginal;
  });
  $("#btn").on('click', function() {
    var conteudo = document.getElementById('impri').innerHTML,
      tela_impressao = window.open('_blank');
    tela_impressao.document.write(conteudo);
    tela_impressao.window.print();
    tela_impressao.window.close();
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <br><br>
  <div class="container">
    <button id="imprimir" class="btn btn-success">
            Print 1
        </button>
    <button id="btn" class="btn btn-info">
            Print 2
        </button>
    <br><br>
    <div id="impri">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Intenta con `$(document).on('click', '#imprimir', function(){` en vez de dar clic al id haces sobre el **documento en el id** de igual manera el otro.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, tengo aun otra duda el boton print 2 abre en otra ventana pero no con los estilos adecuados. como podria solucionar...

Comment: Por cierto, ¿sabes que puedes definir estilos [para imprimir y otros para mostrar en pantalla](http://desarrolloweb.dlsi.ua.es/libros/html-css/como-crear-una-hoja-de-estilo-para-impresion)? Lo mismo te simplifica mucho tu trabajo...

Comment: Esta bien imprimir en la misma página ya que abre una ventana de imprimir, pero después de cerrar o cancelar la ventana de imprimir quiero cerrar la ventana modal no me permite. cuál es motivo ? el código es esta <br>'$(document).on('click', '#imprimir', function(){
    var contenido= document.getElementById("impri").innerHTML;
    var contenidoOriginal= document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = contenido;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = contenidoOriginal;
  });'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para el primer problema la solución es indicarle que tienes que dar clic al **document** y de ahí al **id**

`$(document).on('click', '#imprimir', function()`

La segunda cuestión es porque cuando creas una nueva página con `_blank`, no le pasas los estilos y demás. Solución:

```
    function printDiv(divName) {
            var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
            var document_html = window.open("_blank");
             document_html.document.write( "<html><head><title></title>" );
             document_html.document.write( "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css\" type=\"text/css\"/>" );
             document_html.document.write( "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css\" type=\"text/css\"/>" );
             document_html.document.write( "</head><body>" );
             document_html.document.write( printContents );
             document_html.document.write( "</body></html>" );
             setTimeout(function () {
                   document_html.print();
               }, 500)
}
```

La forma de utilizarlo es:

```
$(document).on('click','#imprimir' ,function() {
    printDiv('impri')
});
```